# Animate div size on hover and reveal image

Tags: jquery-ui

> Blockquote

How do I animate a div width to certain width from its middle(on hover)

Answer (score 1):

css to set the div to center itself:

```
#divname {width:200px;margin:0px auto;}
```

jquery:

```
$('#divname').hover(
 function(){
  $(this).animate({width:'400px'},300);
 },
 function() {
  $(this).animate({width:'200px'},300);
 });
```

alternatively if you don't want to center the div, but still wan't to make the div grow from the middle, you can have animate marginLeft:

css:

```
#divname {width:200px;}
```

jquery:

```
$('#divname').hover(
 function(){
  $(this).animate({width:'400px',marginLeft:'-100px'},300);
 },
 function() {
  $(this).animate({width:'200px',marginLeft:'0px'},300);
 });
```